# How to show multiple locations in googlemap view

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I found there is questions asked in stackoverflow regarding this topic before but i didnt get any solution. I have latitude and longitudes of 5 different cities. I want to show them in google map. How can I achieve this

Thanks

Comment: You mention a question, what question exactly?

Comment: NickT mentiones ItemizedOverlay in his answer. His answer is correct as long as you don't need to mark more than a dozen cities (you write 5 - that's ok). If it will become more use Overlay instead. ItemizedOverlay is optimized for few items only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an **ItemizedOverlay**.

Part 2 of the following example shows how:

[Google Map View](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

Comment: This has been  Deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Hay guys [hear](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) you get a perfect example to implement this.